# Compress/minify JavaScript file in Jekyll

Tags: javascript, jekyll, minify

I have a blog built with Jekyll and I want to minify my JavaScript file. I'm currently compressing/minifying my Sass file with the following in config.yml:

```
assets:
  compress:
    css:            sass
    js:             uglifier
  autoprefixer:
    browsers:       ["> 1%"]
  plugins:
    css: { autoprefixer: {} }
  sass:
    sass_dir:       _sass
    style:          :compressed
```

Even though `uglifier` is listed under `compress: js`, it's not actually compressing/minifying the JS file. I'm not using any Ruby gems. The only Jekyll plugins I'm using are:

```
plugins:
  - jekyll-paginate
  - jekyll-autoprefixer
```

How can I compress/minify the JavaScript?